# Homotopy of group actions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory, group-actions

Let $G$ be a topological group and $X$ be a topological space.
Let $\alpha$, $\beta:G\times X\to X$ be two group actions. We say that these two actions are homotopic actions if there is a continuous path of actions connecting $\alpha$ to $\beta$. This means that there is a continuous function $\Gamma:[0,1]\times G\times X \to X$ such that each $\Gamma_t$ is a group action and we have $\Gamma_0=\alpha, \Gamma_1=\beta$.

**Question 1:** What is an example of the following situation:
 There are two group actions $\alpha$, $\beta$ by $G=S^1$ on a manifold $M$ which are not homotopic actions but for every $g\in G$, the two homeomorphisms $\alpha_g$, $\beta_g$ of $M$ are homotopic maps?

**Question 2:** What is an example of the following situation:
 There are two group actions $\alpha$, $\beta$ by $ G=S^1$ on a manifold $M$ which are not homotopic actions but $\alpha, \beta$ are homotopic maps as maps from $G\times X$ to $X$?

Comment: It should be enough to pick a contractible manifold with non-contractible diffeomorphism group (e.g. $\mathbb{R}^n$)

Comment: Q 1 : $S^1$ acting on $S^1$ by complex multiplication and by identity

Comment: @Bleuderk That answers Q2 also (by taking the other action to be trivial)

Comment: @DenisNardin You mean by taking action on the whole $\mathbb C$ ?

Comment: @Bleuderk Oh yes, sorry. For some reason I thought you wrote $S^1$ acting on $\mathbb{C}$...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's enough to pick a contractible manifold $M$ with two non-homotopic actions. For example, let us pick $M=\mathbb{R}^2$ with two actions of $S^1$, the trivial one and the one given by rotations. These two actions are not homotopic. In fact for every action $\rho$ of $S^1$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ we can consider the map $\mathbb{R}^2\times S^1\to GL_2^+(\mathbb{R})$ sending $(x,\lambda)$ to the differential of $\rho(\lambda)$ at $x$. This map is clearly homotopy invariant under the action, and its degree as a map $S^1\to S^1$ is 0 for the trivial action and 1 for the defining action.

However all continuous maps with target $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homotopic.

Comment: This answers the second question. For the first, just take $n\ge 2$ and choose the nontrivial action using a element of order 2 and determinant 1.

Comment: @YCor Sorry, the addition of $G=S^1$ was later. Will amend my answer (pretty much the same thing works, of course)

Comment: Also, if I'm not mistaken, question 1 is true for any action, since $S^1$ is a connected Lie group (so for every $g$, $\alpha_g$ is homotopic to the identity...)